# Can we turn $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ into a Hilbert Space/ Inner product space

Tags: differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces, riemannian-geometry, inner-products

Given a Compact, Riemannian Manifold $(M,g)$, I'm wondering if we can induce an inner product space on $\mathfrak{X}(M)$, the set of smooth vector fields on $M$ that might have some interesting properties. My tentative definition will be:

Given $X,Y\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$  we'll take $$X\cdot Y=\int_M g(X,Y)dvol_{M}$$ Since $X,Y$ are smooth and $M$ is compact, we can see that this product will be defined for any vector-fields on $M$, and that this product will be positive definite, since $g_p$ is positive definite on $T_pM$ for all $p\in M$.

I believe, that in order to make it complete we would have to do quite a bit of extra work and define some kind of completion on this space since vector spaces of differentiable functions don't end up being complete due to the restrictiveness of differentiability. What kind of work would have to be done to turn the underlying structure into something resembling a well-behaved vectorspace?

Would the properties of such a space tell us anything about the underlying structure of $M$? Are there some notions that I missed, ending up making this space ultimately uninteresting?

Comment: Well, $L^2(M;TM)$ (or the [Sobolev space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space) variant $L^2_k(M;TM)$ also written as $H_k(M;TM)$ or $W^{k,2}(M;TM)$) is a separable Hilbert space just like any other infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space such as $\ell_2$.  So no, just from the Hilbert space alone you can't tell anything about $M$.  You need to introduce other things to it that is specific to $M$, e.g., Laplacian, or meanings like index at each $p$, to recover some information about $M$.

Comment: @user10354138 So one could use a construction like this would be used to study vector PDE's on manifolds à la Sobolev spaces?

Comment: Yes, and we do this all the time in things like ASD connections on 4D manifold (Yang-Mill instantons) or minimal submanifolds.